# Node Js mySQL updating multiple rows with array of arrays

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've got a dynamically assigned number of rows which I need to update. I created an array of arrays to keep all of those values and send them in one query. Each array contains three values A - a value which I want to update and B, C - keys necessary to recognize which row need to be updated.

```
var arrData = [];
arrData[0] = [43,54,67];
arrData[1] = [56,68,75];
arrData[2] = [43,67,75];
...
var query = "UPDATE my_table SET A_row = ? WHERE B_row = ? AND C_row = ?";

connection.query(query,[arrData], function(err,response){

if(err)
{
     console.log(err)
}    
else{ ... });
```

But then I get this error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND C_row = ?' at line 1

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Each ? needs to resolve to an actual value. So you need a loop with a counter to set the index on the array and call the query ... something like,
...

```
for(cnt=0;cnt< length;cnt++) {

   connection.query(query,arrData[cnt], function(err,response){
   if(err){console.log(err)
   else{ ... });
```

Comment: ok thanks. But what If I need to proceed my code only when every query will succeed? In this case: send user a 200 response code. Should I apply a promise or something like that?

Comment: You need to wrap the whole for() loop in a promise.  break the for() loop on error.